# Pandas iterate max value of a variable length slice in a series

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

Let's assume i have a Pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
idx = ['2003-01-02', '2003-01-03', '2003-01-06', '2003-01-07',
       '2003-01-08', '2003-01-09', '2003-01-10', '2003-01-13',
       '2003-01-14', '2003-01-15', '2003-01-16', '2003-01-17',
       '2003-01-21', '2003-01-22', '2003-01-23', '2003-01-24',
       '2003-01-27']

a = pd.DataFrame([1,2,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1],
                  columns = ['original'], index = pd.to_datetime(idx))
```

I am trying to get the max for each slices of that DataFrame between two zeros. 
In that example i would get:

```
a['result'] = [0,2,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,1]
```

that is:

```
            original  result
2003-01-02         1       0
2003-01-03         2       2
2003-01-06         0       0
2003-01-07         0       0
2003-01-08         1       0
2003-01-09         2       0
2003-01-10         3       3
2003-01-13         0       0
2003-01-14         0       0
2003-01-15         0       0
2003-01-16         1       0
2003-01-17         2       0
2003-01-21         3       0
2003-01-22         4       0
2003-01-23         5       5
2003-01-24         0       0
2003-01-27         1       1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- find zeros
- `cumsum` to make groups
- `mask` the zeros into their own group `-1`
- find the max location in each group `idxmax`
- get rid of the one for group `-1`, that was for zeros anyway
- get `a.original` for found max locations, reindex and fill with zeros

---

```
m = a.original.eq(0)
g = a.original.groupby(m.cumsum().mask(m, -1))
i = g.idxmax().drop(-1)
a.assign(result=a.loc[i, 'original'].reindex(a.index, fill_value=0))

            original  result
2003-01-02         1       0
2003-01-03         2       2
2003-01-06         0       0
2003-01-07         0       0
2003-01-08         1       0
2003-01-09         2       0
2003-01-10         3       3
2003-01-13         0       0
2003-01-14         0       0
2003-01-15         0       0
2003-01-16         1       0
2003-01-17         2       0
2003-01-21         3       0
2003-01-22         4       0
2003-01-23         5       5
2003-01-24         0       0
2003-01-27         1       1
```